# rbind time and value vectors of different lengths from list to data.frame

Tags: r, list, plyr, rbind

In advance I appologize for not providing a reproducible example but I hope that
the case gets clear through my description

I have a long list of asset prices and a date attached to them. 
The list looks like this

```
> my.list

[[1]]
AT0000743059.time     AT0000743059
1          02.01.2012       24.020
2          03.01.2012       24.225
3          04.01.2012       24.130
4          05.01.2012       23.935


[[2]]
AT0000743055.time     AT0000743055
1          02.01.2012       24.020
2          03.01.2012       24.225
3          04.01.2012       24.130
4          05.01.2012       23.935
5          09.01.2012       24.060
```

Not all of the objects in the list have the same length.
What I need is to rbind every object in the list next to each other such that the output looks like that

```
    AT0000743059.time AT0000743059  AT0000743055.time     AT0000743055
1          02.01.2012       24.020         02.01.2012           24.020
2          03.01.2012       24.225         03.01.2012           24.225
3          04.01.2012       24.130         04.01.2012           24.130
4          05.01.2012       23.935         05.01.2012           23.935
5          NA               NA             09.01.2012           24.060
```

using plyr's ldply ends in

```
> plyr::ldply(my.list, cbind)

    AT0000743059.time AT0000743059  AT0000743055.time  AT0000743055
1          02.01.2012       24.020  NA                 NA       
2          03.01.2012       24.225  NA                 NA
3          04.01.2012       24.130  NA                 NA       
4          05.01.2012       23.935  NA                 NA       
5                                   02.01.2012         24.020
6                                   03.01.2012         24.225
7                                   04.01.2012         24.130
8                                   05.01.2012         23.935
9                                   09.01.2012         24.060
```

Moving the NAs to the bottom and deleting them afterwards results in trouble 
with the dates who get transformed in some strange way. I hope there is an efficient
way to handle this problem. Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you actually want to rbind them, or rather join them on the time columns which seems more reasonable?

Comment: @ Wannes Rosiers: That would also be a solution I could deal with. Do you say one could convert the list into a big xts object?

Answer (score 0):

For now, the merging is defined in a loop, probably not at all as desired, but this gives you the output I suggested:

```
my.list <-list(
  data.frame(AT0000743059.time = c("02.01.2012","03.01.2012","04.01.2012","05.01.2012"),
         AT0000743059 = c(24.020,24.225,24.130,23.935),
         stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
  data.frame(AT0000743055.time = c("02.01.2012","03.01.2012","04.01.2012","05.01.2012","09.01.2012"),
         AT0000743055 = c(24.020,24.225,24.130,23.935,24.060),
         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
)

result <- my.list[[1]]
colnames(result)[1] <- "time"

for (i in 2:length(my.list)){
  temp <- my.list[[i]]
  colnames(temp)[1] <- "time"
  result <- merge(result, temp,all = TRUE)
}
```

The only difference with your desired output is that I have only kept one time column, since it is the time of every measured value in that row.